# Laravel Eloquent where string column

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Sql like this, When I query device_id = 0, there is data. If device_id = null, there is no data. I have researched and don't know why device_id = 0 is querying the wrong data as shown, please help me.

Sorry, my english not good

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rzww.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liE9p.png)

why device_id = 0 is querying the wrong data as shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the query `SELECT * FROM access_devices WHERE hapilogi_user_id='3' AND device_id=0` is fetching results even though `device_id` is an empty value is because the comparison operator `=` is being used to compare an empty value to the literal value 0. In SQL, an empty value is considered to be equal to NULL, not 0. Therefore, the query is actually returning all of the rows where `hapilogi_user_id` is equal to 3 and `device_id is NULL`.

To Fix this issue try anyone of the following way

```
SELECT * FROM access_devices WHERE hapilogi_user_id='3' AND device_id IS NULL
```

`or`

```
SELECT * FROM access_devices WHERE hapilogi_user_id='3' AND device_id=''
```

Comment: thank you so much, this ans really resolve my problem